# Rotate iOS Image Clockwise

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uianimation

I am trying to animate my image by having it rotate clockwise, and shrink down.  So far, it is only going counter-clockwise.  I have tried both positive and negative values for the value/Key path of rotating along Z, but it changed nothing.

```
[window addSubview:splashView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 284, 0, 0);
    [splashView.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-360]
                       forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You want to rotate the image by 360°?

Comment: I'm toying around with exactly how much, but am thinking make it spin completely around at least twice while it is shrinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate **in specific direction** more than 360°use `CAKeyframeAnimation`. There you can set not only the final value, but also some **intermediate values**.

```
// consider this to be pseudo code
keyFrameAnimation.values = @[ 90, 180, 270, 360, 450, 540, ... ];
```

I don't have any code to show you, but this is defnitely the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use M_PI directly.

- `M_PI_4` = 45 degrees
- `M_PI_2` = 90 degrees
- `M_PI` = 180 degrees
- `M_PI*2` = 360 degrees

You can also set your transform more easily.

```
// set transform
splashView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI*2, 0, 0, 1);
```

instead of

```
[splashView.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-360] 
                forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

Comment: That line of code just made the view shrink without doing any rotation.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're passing degrees to the animation when it wants radians. Here's an example of how to make the conversion.

```
float degrees = 90.0f;
float radians = degrees * (180.0f / M_PI);
```

Comment: Ok...........so where do I put that and what do I set for the setValue in my code?

Comment: @user717452 Are you serious?

Comment: I asked how to make something spin clockwise and you gave me two float values with nothing else at all.